# Create a restful service (use Azure AD to do the authentication and authorization ) as a central authentication service

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, restful-authentication

I want to create a restful service (use Azure AD to do the authentication and authorization ) as a central authentication service, other services can use this service to do the authentication, and also implement single sign-on for other services.

Is this technically feasible with Azure Active Directory and Spring security?

Example Scenario:

1. A User tries to access a protected resource, but is not authenticated.
2. The application redirects the user to the central authentication service. (The application not directly redirect to Azure, redirect to auth service, then auth service talk to Azure)
3. If being authenticated the user gets a token from the central authentication service.
4. The central authentication service redirects to the original application.
5. The original application checks the token against the central authentication service.
   (maybe this is not required? because Azure AD return JWT token)
   If the token is ok, access will be allowed and the application knows of the user id.
6. The user performs a log-out and is logged out from all connected application at the same time (single sign-out).

All the services are registered web application in Azure AD.

Comment: Could you share a bit more on what you are looking to achieve with this? What functionality is the "SSO server" providing?

Comment: Hi @PhilippeSignoret,

For the "SSO server", I mean the central authentication service which I want to create with Spring security and Azure Active Directory.
Already updated the description, sorry for the confusion.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, but why? What functionality do you want to implement in this "central authentication service"? I'm assuming you want to add some functionality that is not available in Azure AD (otherwise you'd just point your apps to Azure AD directory)--what is that functionality?

Comment: We have multiple micro services, I don't want to point each service to Azure AD. Instead I want to have a central authentication service, it also can implement the SSO. right now this authentication service talks to Azure AD, maybe later will add some other authentication provider to it, like Client's LDAP.

Comment: Sounds like you want a central token service which federates with AAD or B2C so you can login the user once (SSO if they are AAD users) and from there one your central service creates the tokens and does the authorization with the backend correct?

Comment: Hi Matthijs Hoekstra, Yes, that's correct. Now for single backend webservice I can make it work with AAD, but for multiple services, seems I can't use same token for different services.Token for service A can't be used to call service B, and calling service B from service A use RestTemplate or OAuth2RestTemplate, the token can be relayed to service B, but there is a 302 redirect error. Each services are registered in AAD, it has a unique Client ID, and token issued by AAD is a JWT token which contains a Client ID inside, so same token can't be used for different services, am I correct?